# Change some fields in a file

Tags: ruby, string, file

I need to analyses a file and change some fields.
Example:

```
<taskdef uri="xxxxxx" resource="/mnt/data/yyy.xml">
    <classpath path="/mnt/data/test.jar"/>
</taskdef>

<target name="test"
    description="this is a xml file">
       <fileset dir="/tmp/data/output/test_1/" includes=all/>
```

In my case I need to find this part:

```
    <fileset dir="/tmp/data/output/test_1/" includes=all/>
```

and change just the name (for example) **test_1**
At the end, save the file

Comment: Use Nokogiri, parse the xml and do all change you need. Then save the XML to a new file.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use libraries like Nokogiri to parse the file

Comment: No worry.. use http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/index.html

Comment: you could use a regex to find that but it is a bad idea to reinvent the wheel, why can't you use gems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  your comment you say you "cannot use libraries like Nogokiri to parse the file". So I can only guess you're not doing full XML parsing.

Assuming you do not have to parse XML you could just use Ruby's [String.replace](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-replace) method on the line in question. Just iterate over the lines in the file until you get to the one in quesion and call replace. Here's some pseudocode.

```
open file
for each line
  is this what I want to change
  change line
save (new) file
```

Comment: You are right (sorry I think my post is not clear), I'm doing a generic parse. Now I'm reading each line with File.readlines(FILE).each do |line|  and then split them with line_parsed = line.split(/ <=">/). But then in line_parse[1] I have NIL... any idea?

Comment: Add your code snippet to the question. That, along with sample data, will help us determine your problem.